# how to display hierarchy in search bar

Tags: design, search-results, hierarchy

So we have an internal form creating tool and the names of data here are very repetitive. We decided to bring in a search bar and show the data along with the hierarchy( basically the path of the file). Any clue on how to display it efficiently in a user friendly and pleasing manner?[image: This is the search bar i mentioned and there is a small button to the right of fourth result in search bar. I decided to display the entire hieracrchy on hovering the button.]

[image: This is how it will look on hovering the button]

Comment: Can you show the work you've done so far? It's kind of hard to give any "best practices" if we don't know where to start.

Comment: hello. I've edited the document by adding pictures. the first picture is how it looks when the keywords are entered. there is a small button on the right side of 4th result. On hovering the button the result will expand to a detail explanation of the hierarchy( like the one shown in second picture). Is there any other effective way to do it? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for what is called autocomplete.  What environment are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the answers to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72350/best-way-to-show-search-results-for-different-content-types), and [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66879/single-search-box-for-different-types-of-searched-criteria).

If you visit https://www.amazon.co.uk/ and type 'truck' in their search bar you get two sections, the first for your query in all the different departments, and the second for wild-card searches. Perhaps this may inform your decision.

A project I'm working on at the moment deals with deep-hierarchy searches like yours. At present I'm looking at providing a quick high-level view of where each node in the results sits:

[image: Search results]

Clicking on the result will expand a separate hierarchy view, so you can see nodes on the same branch and make your selection from there. I find this better than trying to cram too much into the search results, and am hoping that searching and viewing the expanded hierarchy will be smooth enough to mitigate the lack of definition in the search result description and potential confusion that could result.

That being said, my data may not have as much similarity as yours does, so this may not work in your case. Also I should say that this is quite early-stage and I haven't put it in front of any users yet (that's next week!).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This did give me a different perspective to approach the problem I am facing :).